# Can I post reviews on Facebook through an API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to post user reviews to a FB page via an API?

I want to have an app on a phone that will let users review my business when they walk in to my store.

Edit:- This is what I've tried so far.

I used the passport module in Nodejs for authentication and was able to retrieve the access token from FB, including manage_pages, publish_pages and read_insights.

```
 app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email', 'manage_pages','publish_pages','read_insights' ]}));
```

My passport strategy has this

```
    clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID, //my app's client id
    clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret, //my app's client secret
    callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL, //the callback URL after authentication
    profileFields: ["emails", "displayName"]
```

I am able to post as the page using the NPM FBGraph module.

```
var graph = require('fbgraph');
graph.setAccessToken(req.user.facebook.token);

graph.post("{My page's ID}/feed", "Message test", function(err, res) {
  console.log(res); // { id: xxxxx}
});
```

This lets me post the "Message test" to my page's feed.

I am not able to find a reference to post reviews for the page through the Graph API though and was wondering if that is possible.

Comment: what have you tried so far? where is your research and code? did you check out the official docs already?

Comment: Sorry for not giving any details initially. I've edited the question now to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings#Creating

> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

Meaning, it´s not possible. Not sure what you would do with `publish_pages` though, because ratings/reviews are made by users, not by pages...If it would be possible, then only with `publish_actions`.

Comment: Thank you, @luschn

I'm a beginner with the facebook graph api and didn't know this.